# Pushing local repository to server

Tags: git, git-push

Up till now, I worked on a local repository ( locally initialized, not cloned ). Because I am working on more than one workstation, I decided to "go online" and want to push my repo to server. Also, I want to push all branches.

So question is:
Is there any way of pushing whole locally initialized repo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make things easier, start by creating a remote if you haven't already:

```
git remote add origin <server repo url>
```

Now you can do this:

```
git push --all
```

to push all branches to origin, the default remote. (If you name it something else, you'd have to specify it as an argument.)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to create a bare repository first?

Comment: @Htbaa: Yes, you have to create a repository before you can push to it. I assumed the OP had already done that, since they'd gone on to asking about how to push *all* branches.

Comment: @Jefromi is there any why to push without creating bare repo(i mean is it possible that server creates it automatically link heroku does)

Comment: @ANinJa If you have a new question, please ask a new question (though it's likely a duplicate at this point).

Comment: this answer is incomplete. If I do a `git init` on the remote first then the issue is there's a conflict because it will already have a master branch. If I do `git init --bare` now that folder is some special unusable *bare* git repo. can you please post ALL the commands needed to do push a local repo to a remote server. Assume no folders exist yet on the server.